# StopIteration raised after breaking out of while loop

Tags: python

For the subject method, I'm trying to loop back to the first while loop if an exception is caught within the nested while loop. However a `StopIteration` error is raised when it after the statement `print("\nCannot perform suggested play...")`. What would be causing for the `StopIteration` error to be raised, and how I can overcome this to achieve the desired result?

```
> c:\..\classes.py(143)make_play()
-> break
(Pdb) n
> c:\..\classes.py(147)make_play()
-> print("\nCannot perform suggested play...")
(Pdb) n
StopIteration
> c:\..\classes.py(147)make_play()
-> print("\nCannot perform suggested play...")
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\..\classes.py(147)make_play()->None
```

```
    def make_play(self, player_hand, dealer_hand):
        while True:
            print(f'''
                     {self}               'Dealer'
                ===============       ===============
                {player_hand}         {dealer_hand}
            ''')
            while True:
                play = input(
                    "How would you like to play your hand?\n>>> "
                ).upper()
                matched_play = re.match(r'HIT|STAND|DOUBLE DOWN|SPLIT', play)
                if matched_play:
                    if play == "DOUBLE DOWN" or play == "SPLIT":
                        try:
                            self.bet()
                        except BetError as e:
                            print(f'\n{e}')
                            sleep(1)
                            cls()
                            break # break out of nested while loop
                        else:
                            pass
                    return play
            print("\nCannot perform suggested play...")
            sleep(1)
            cls() # loop back to top of method
```

Comment: How do you break out of the first `while` loop?

Comment: What is `sleep`?

Comment: And what is `cls`?

Comment: `sleep` was imported from the `time` module .  `cls` is just clearing the console. I'm not trying to break out of the first loop. The purpose of the first loop is to loop back to the first print statement if an exception is caught within the nested loop. The only to exit the function altogether is within the nested loop if it has a permitted value.